# How to create nested center and south in jQuery UI Layout Plug-in?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I create nested inner centers and inner souths? The following doesn't seem to do anything other than display "Inner Center" and "Inner South"? How can I make it show the layout resizer for Inner Center and Inner South?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="ui-layout-center">
            Center
            <div class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</div>
            <div class="ui-layout-south">Inner South</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
        <div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html

^Similar to this but with a "Inner Center" and "Inner South" in the "Center" area.

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: Zero errors in the console. I also added some more information to the description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have nested layouts you need to call `layout` for each container where you want the nesting. So you need to mark your current `ui-layout-center` where you have the nested container e.g. with an `id`:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center" id="inner">
    <div class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</div>
    <div class="ui-layout-south">Inner South</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
```

And call again the `layout` on `#inner` to create the nested layout:

```
$('body').layout({
     applyDefaultStyles: true
});
$('#inner').layout({
     applyDefaultStyles: true
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/)

See also the [offical complex demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html)

Comment: Do you have any website recommendations on what I should study to understand the relationships in this type of development regarding div id and classes? I can program in C# but I'm not familiar with web development. Any direction that would help me ramp up quickly would be wonderful.

Comment: codecademy.com has some decent, not too patronising HTML and CSS tutorials

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to check those out.